# Most performant way to update rows on large tables

Tags: sql, performance, mariadb

I have 2 tables:

**Request:**

```
idㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤaccountㅤㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤsubaccountㅤ|ㅤamountㅤ|ㅤㅤupdatedAmount    

1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ12ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ10.2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤnull       
2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ45ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ0ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤnull          
3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ11ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ50.6ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤnull
```

**DailyData:**

```
idㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤaccountㅤㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤsubaccountㅤ|ㅤamountㅤ

1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ45ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ3.12     
2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ12ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ15        
3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ11ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ1.09     
4ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ70ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ30.6     
5ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ11ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ50.6
```

I need to update the column updatedAmount in the Request table, meeting this criteria:

-It updates a row only if it finds a row in the DailyData table with the same account AND subaccount.
-It only updates if the value on the column amount is different in each table.

For the rows where this criteria meets, it saves the amount (from DailyData table) in the updatedAmount (Request table) column.

So for this example we would have this output, only the id 1 updates:

```
idㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤaccountㅤㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤsubaccountㅤ|ㅤamountㅤ|ㅤㅤupdatedAmount    

1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_1ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ12ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ10.2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ15              
2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_2ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ45ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ0ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤnull                    
3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤACCOUNT_3ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤㅤ11ㅤㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤ50.6ㅤㅤ|ㅤㅤnull
```

My big problem is the performance. This is a daily process, and the Request table will have + than 1 million rows, while the DailyProcess table is around 300k rows that change every day.
So far I created 2 methods but both take a lot of time.

1:

```
UPDATE Request r                                              
LEFT OUTER JOIN DailyData d                                              
ON r.account = d.account AND r.subaccount = d.subaccount                                              
SET r.updatedAmount = d.amount
```

2:

```
UPDATE Request r, DailyData d                                              
SET r.updatedAmount = d.amount                                              
WHERE r.account = d.account AND r.subaccount = d.subaccount AND r.amount <> d.amount
```

Can someone suggest any faster method? Any help would be very much apreciated

Comment: What indexes have you created? A compound index on account/sub account on both tables will probably help.

Comment: Look at (and share here) the [*query plans* used](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html). This will indicate if the query can benefit from new indices (and which ones) or other tweaks to encourage a different plan.

Comment: The query plan selection can also occasionally show other artifacts like bad plans selected from good canidate indexes due to bad statistics. The question should also be updated to include any current indices, as part of the shown schema.

Comment: Finally, **the two update approaches shown have different behavior** (the first update will assign NULL amounts to Request for items that are missing from DailyData; it will also cause all Request records to be updated, even if the value is the same). Which behavior is correct?

Answer (score 2):

I mean you can use `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE Request r                                              
INNER JOIN DailyData d                                              
    ON r.account = d.account AND r.subaccount = d.subaccount                                              
SET r.updatedAmount = d.amount
WHERE r.amount <> d.amount;
```

The update performance can be increased by create index (account, subaccount) for both tables

Comment: (fwiw on MySQL, LEFT join is, inexplicably, pretty much always faster than INNER JOIN, haven't heard a convincing theory on why, but it wins the benchmarks every time)

Comment: The LEFT *OUTER* join in the original query may or may not be a mistake (especially as the behavior between the two posted queries differs). However, using an *INNER* join will change the behavior and such should be explicitly mentioned so the correct (per desired outcome) behavior is used.